# How to create cartesian product

Tags: iterator, go, cartesian-product

I have a list of integers, `a = [0, ..., n]`. I want to generate all possible combinations of k elements from a; i.e., the cartesian product of the a with itself k times. Note that n and k are both changeable at runtime, so this needs to be at least a somewhat adjustable function.

So if n was 3, and k was 2:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
k = 2

desired = [(0,0), (0, 1), (0, 2), ..., (2,3), (3,0), ..., (3,3)]
```

In python I would use the itertools.product() function:

```
for p in itertools.product(a, repeat=2):
    print p
```

What's an idiomatic way to do this **in Go**?

Initial guess is a closure that returns a slice of integers, but it doesn't feel very clean.

Answer (score 7):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func nextProduct(a []int, r int) func() []int {
    p := make([]int, r)
    x := make([]int, len(p))
    return func() []int {
        p := p[:len(x)]
        for i, xi := range x {
            p[i] = a[xi]
        }
        for i := len(x) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
            x[i]++
            if x[i] < len(a) {
                break
            }
            x[i] = 0
            if i <= 0 {
                x = x[0:0]
                break
            }
        }
        return p
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []int{0, 1, 2, 3}
    k := 2
    np := nextProduct(a, k)
    for {
        product := np()
        if len(product) == 0 {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(product)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[0 0]
[0 1]
[0 2]
[0 3]
[1 0]
[1 1]
[1 2]
[1 3]
[2 0]
[2 1]
[2 2]
[2 3]
[3 0]
[3 1]
[3 2]
[3 3]
```

Comment: about to return and post something similar. Here's this algorithm in a nice single function http://play.golang.org/p/qkr5BUMpGT

Comment: @JimB: [Python: itertools — Functions creating iterators for efficient looping: memory efficient tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). You are not memory efficient.

Comment: true, I wasn't thinking about replicating the python generator, just the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

The code to find the next product in lexicographic order is simple: starting from the right, find the first value that won't roll over when you increment it, increment that and zero the values to the right.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    n, k := 5, 2
    ix := make([]int, k)
    for {
        fmt.Println(ix)
        j := k - 1
        for ; j >= 0 && ix[j] == n-1; j-- {
            ix[j] = 0
        }
        if j < 0 {
            return
        }
        ix[j]++
    }
}
```

I've changed "n" to mean the set is [0, 1, ..., n-1] rather than [0, 1, ..., n] as given in the question, since the latter is confusing since it has n+1 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the answer [Implement Ruby style Cartesian product in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002724/implement-ruby-style-cartesian-product-in-go), play it on http://play.golang.org/p/NR1_3Fsq8F

```
package main

import "fmt"

// NextIndex sets ix to the lexicographically next value,
// such that for each i>0, 0 <= ix[i] < lens.
func NextIndex(ix []int, lens int) {
    for j := len(ix) - 1; j >= 0; j-- {
        ix[j]++
        if j == 0 || ix[j] < lens {
            return
        }
        ix[j] = 0
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []int{0, 1, 2, 3}
    k := 2
    lens := len(a)
    r := make([]int, k)
    for ix := make([]int, k); ix[0] < lens; NextIndex(ix, lens) {
        for i, j := range ix {
            r[i] = a[j]
        }
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```