# Implement Ruby style Cartesian product in Go

Tags: go, cartesian-product

I want to get the Cartesian product of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`:

```
a = ['a1']
b = ['b1', 'b2']
c = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
d = ['d1']
```

Here is code in Ruby:

```
e = [b, c, d]
print a.product(*e)
```

Output is:

```
[
  ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"],
  ["a1", "b1", "c2", "d1"],
  ["a1", "b1", "c3", "d1"],
  ["a1", "b2", "c1", "d1"],
  ["a1", "b2", "c2", "d1"],
  ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d1"]
]
```

Is there a similar package or function that could do product in Golang?
This is just simplified version, in fact, the input data is like [['a1'], ['b1','b2'], ['c1','c2','c3],['d1'],['e1',...],...].

Comment: Yes: Three nested for loops.

Comment: You could look on [godoc.org](https://godoc.org/) or [go-search.org](http://go-search.org/) for a matrix package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need an unknown-at-compile-time set of nested index loops, you can use code like this.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// NextIndex sets ix to the lexicographically next value,
// such that for each i>0, 0 <= ix[i] < lens(i).
func NextIndex(ix []int, lens func(i int) int) {
    for j := len(ix) - 1; j >= 0; j-- {
        ix[j]++
        if j == 0 || ix[j] < lens(j) {
            return
        }
        ix[j] = 0
    }
}

func main() {
    e := [][]string{
        {"a1"},
        {"b1", "b2"},
        {"c1", "c2", "c3"},
        {"d1"},
    }
    lens := func(i int) int { return len(e[i]) }

    for ix := make([]int, len(e)); ix[0] < lens(0); NextIndex(ix, lens) {
        var r []string
        for j, k := range ix {
            r = append(r, e[j][k])
        }
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[a1 b1 c1 d1]
[a1 b1 c2 d1]
[a1 b1 c3 d1]
[a1 b2 c1 d1]
[a1 b2 c2 d1]
[a1 b2 c3 d1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [@paul-hankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400793/paul-hankin) answer, here a solution which is embedded in a function and uses generics. Needs go 1.18 minimum

```
// cartesianProduct returns the cartesian product
// of a given matrix
func cartesianProduct[T any](matrix [][]T) [][]T {
    // nextIndex sets ix to the lexicographically next value,
    // such that for each i>0, 0 <= ix[i] < lens(i).
    nextIndex := func(ix []int, lens func(i int) int) {
        for j := len(ix) - 1; j >= 0; j-- {
            ix[j]++

            if j == 0 || ix[j] < lens(j) {
                return
            }

            ix[j] = 0
        }
    }

    lens := func(i int) int { return len(matrix[i]) }

    results := make([][]T, 0, len(matrix))
    for indexes := make([]int, len(matrix)); indexes[0] < lens(0); nextIndex(indexes, lens) {
        var temp []T

        for j, k := range indexes {
            temp = append(temp, matrix[j][k])
        }

        results = append(results, temp)
    }

    return results
}
```